# Reading from a file, storing values, and math operations

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to read in from a file that contains city names, an odometer reading, and how much fuel is left. The contents of the text file are:

```
Kennewick 97840.4 40.0<br>
Benton_City 97861.3 37.6<br>
Prosser 97878.2 35.9<br>
Grandview 97886.5 35.0<br>
Sunnyside 97894.6 34.1<br>
Granger 97904.6 33.1<br>
Toppenish 97913.0 32.2<br>
Wapato 97921.7 31.3<br>
Union_Gap 97931.6 30.4<br>
Yakima 97935.2 30.0<br>
Selah 97939.4 29.6<br>
Ellensburg 97972.7 26.0<br>
Thorp 97981.1 25.1<br>
Rosyln 98002.8 22.6<br>
Easton 98016.1 21.1<br>
North_Bend 98058.1 16.9<br>
Preston 98067.7 16.0<br>
Issaquah 98073.6 15.4<br>
East_Gate 98082.9 14.4<br>
Mercer_Island 98088.5 13.7<br>
Seattle 98095.4 13.0<br>
```

Part of the assignment is subtracting the current read-through from the last read-through (both of those values stored in the variable miles).

```
def BusRoute():
    path = "C:\\"
    ext = ".txt"

    lines = ""
    stopname = ""
    miles = 0
    prevmiles = 0
    milest = 0
    fuel = 0.0
    mpg = 0.0
    i = 0

    filename = input("Please enter the file name. The file path [C:\...] and extension [*.txt] is not required: ")

    inFile = open(path + filename + ext, "r")

    for lines in inFile:
        stopname, miles, fuel = lines.split(" ")

        miles = float(miles)
        fuel = float(fuel)

        prevmiles = miles

        milest = miles - prevmiles

        miles += 1

        print("Since last stop:", float(milest), "miles")
```

My problem is, I am trying to store the last-read value of `miles` in a variable called `prevmiles`, and then subtract `prevmiles` (the last mileage read) from the CURRENT reading of `miles`, but it keeps subtracting the current `miles` from the current `miles`, obviously making the value that I want printed out 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things going on here:

1. you need to initialize `stopname`, `prevmiles`, and `fuel` with the first line of the file, and
2. you need to swap the two lines where you assign `miles` to `prevmiles`.

Here's the updated function:

```
def BusRoute():
    path = "C:\\"
    ext = ".txt"

    lines = ""
    stopname = ""
    miles = 0
    prevmiles = 0
    milest = 0
    fuel = 0.0
    mpg = 0.0
    i = 0

    filename = input("Please enter the file name (no extension)").strip()

    inFile = open(path + filename + ext, "r")

    stopname, prevmiles, fuel = inFile.readline().split()
    prevmiles = float(prevmiles)
    fuel = float(fuel)

    for lines in inFile:
        stopname, miles, fuel = lines.split(" ")

        miles = float(miles)
        fuel = float(fuel)

        milest = miles - prevmiles

        prevmiles = miles

        miles += 1

        print("Since last stop:", float(milest), "miles")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This code worked; all I did to it was modify it a little bit to be with a consistent format for the rest of my programs.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
prevmiles = miles

milest = miles - prevmiles
```

which guarantees that milest will be 0. Try just switching the order of those two lines.

Comment: So I tried that just now, and it outputs the first "Since last stop: -97840.4 miles", and still prints 0.0 for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the order of the operations. Do the substraction first and then assign a value to prevmiles.

Comment: I think what you're saying is similar to what the other person answered, but it did not work quite the way I need it yet. For the first, it shows "Since last stop: -97840.4 miles", and still prints 0.0 for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the two lines and got what I think you are looking for.

```
prevmiles = miles

milest = miles - prevmiles
```

Note - This code is for Python 2.5.4, so the syntax changes in a few parts, and because of the 
 on the end of the line the floats for fuel were giving errors so I commented that out.

```
def BusRoute():
    path = "C:\\"
    ext = ".txt"

    lines = ""
    stopname = ""
    miles = 0
    prevmiles = 0
    milest = 0
    fuel = 0.0
    mpg = 0.0
    i = 0

    filename = raw_input("Please enter the file name. The file path [C:\...] and extension [*.txt] is not required: ") #raw_input for text in Python 2.5

    inFile = open(path + filename + ext, "r")

    for lines in inFile:
        stopname, miles, fuel = lines.split(" ")

        miles = float(miles)
        ##fuel = float(fuel) (Gives me an error message)

        milest = miles - prevmiles

        prevmiles = miles            

        miles += 1

        print "Since last stop:", float(milest), "miles" #Print syntax is different in Python 2.5

BusRoute()
```

Gives the output:

```
Please enter the file name. The file path [C:\...] and extension [*.txt] is not required: name
Since last stop: 97840.4 miles
Since last stop: 20.9 miles
Since last stop: 16.9 miles
Since last stop: 8.3 miles
Since last stop: 8.10000000001 miles
Since last stop: 10.0 miles
Since last stop: 8.39999999999 miles
Since last stop: 8.7 miles
Since last stop: 9.90000000001 miles
Since last stop: 3.59999999999 miles
Since last stop: 4.2 miles
Since last stop: 33.3 miles
Since last stop: 8.40000000001 miles
Since last stop: 21.7 miles
Since last stop: 13.3 miles
Since last stop: 42.0 miles
Since last stop: 9.59999999999 miles
Since last stop: 5.90000000001 miles
Since last stop: 9.29999999999 miles
Since last stop: 5.60000000001 miles
Since last stop: 6.89999999999 miles
```

Why don't you try to print the miles from the file in the loop to make sure you are getting the right values?

Comment: @Ethan How so? If he wants the first line to print 0 miles then he needs to use a different set of logic.  As it stands, it would make sense that if he sets miles to 0 at the beginning, the first output will be 97840.4

Comment: In one of his other comments he states ... oh, -97840.4 -- guess I should clean my glasses.  Undoing downvote.  Sorry!

Comment: It's alright, I was wondering if that was the issue, no problem :D